# Determining if Xcode StoreKit Configuration file is being used

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, storekit, xcode-scheme

Xcode 12 introduced [StoreKit Configuration files](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/setting-up-storekit-testing-in-xcode) which are great for testing basic StoreKit functionality before delving into App Store Connect, Sandbox and all that.

Is there a way to determine at run-time (or even at compile-time) whether the scheme's `StoreKit Configuration` value is set to 'none' or some file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was just wondering the same, because since I perform local receipt validation, I had to use the right certificate: StoreKit or Apple's root.

The solution is pretty simple: add a new product inside your .storekit file to check if you are using the local config or the sandbox/App Store one.

Add a new product ID called *using_store_kit_conf* then pass the array of IDs to `SKProductsRequest` containing also this one.
When you get the list of products in the delegate, check if the *using_store_kit_conf* product is present to determine if you're using the StoreKit Configuration file.

If you list all your products to the user, remember to filter out the *using_store_kit_conf* product.

[image: storekit file]

Sample:

```
static let premiumOneTime = "premium_one_time"
static let usingStoreKitConfiguration = "using_store_kit_conf"
static let productIds: Set<String> = [InAppPurchase.premiumOneTime, InAppPurchase.usingStoreKitConfiguration]
private var products: [SKProduct] = []
```

Pass all the IDs:

```
productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: InAppPurchase.productIds)
```

Delegate:

```
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
    self.products = response.products
    print("InAppPurchase products: ", response.products)
}
```

Check if using StoreKit Configuration:

```
var isUsingStoreKitConfiguration: Bool {
    products.contains(where: { product in product.productIdentifier == InAppPurchase.usingStoreKitConfiguration })
}
```

NOTE: This only works after you have loaded the products list, otherwise `isUsingStoreKitConfiguration` will always return false.

Comment: Although this isn't the solution I was looking for, it's the best I've come across so far